# Model#typeKey undefined when using Ember Data 1.0 Beta

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to update my Ember.js app to Ember Data 1.0 Beta. What I have is working with Ember Data 0.14. With the new version I need to manually set `typeKey` for a model in order for the REST request to have proper path.

I have simple model:

```
App.Product = DS.Model.extend
name: DS.attr('string')
```

In Ember Data 1.0 Beta I need to add this in order to get it to work:

App.Product.typeKey = 'product'

Otherwise `buildURL` method always get passed `undefined` [`buildURL(type.typeKey, …)`].

Comment: how are you getting records, and what version of Ember Data?

Comment: Even on a canary build I'm not seeing it, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/148/edit

Comment: @kingpin2k I tried with Ember Data 1.0 Beta 4 and Beta 5.
I'm using RESTAdapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by using model class instead of its string name in store finder method:

Should be `@store.find('product')` instead of `@store.find(App.Product)`.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into an issue very similar to this just yesterday. For some reason, I was able to get the `typeKey` for one of my models, but not the other three. It seemed like some kind of issue with the application not being fully loaded or ready. After the page loaded, I was able to get the `typeKey` for all four models just fine. See if you can't get the same result. I just had to rearrange a bit of my code to make it work correctly. Hopefully you can do the same.

Answer (score 0):

One more thing to notice is that `DS.Store` implements `modelFor()` method which you can use to obtain the `Model` class based on the given string key.

For example: `store.modelFor('post');`

I think it's worth using that method since it does other initializations as well.